# hibernate check object exist without id

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am wondering if hibernate offer any function to check whether given persistent object exist without knowing its id or ignore whether the id is equal.

For example, in this scenario:
1. I have a feed taken data from external source. 
2. I have a database table contains feed data accessed via hibernate persistent object.
3. Database table id is auto incremented integer.

Questions:
Is it possible to check whether given persistent data already in the table without adding every fields one by one(some of the field value can be null) to criteria object?  I know I can construct criteria object based on the persistent object's fields and pass to the session. 
is there a smart way to do it?

Comment: Did you try comparing all other columns to be equal with HQL? Like `from X where column1 = :x1 and column2 = :x2`

Comment: I could check that, but the problem is that some columns can be null so HQL won't work here. Instead, I could create a criteria object and add the not null columns, but I am wondering if there are any simple functions in hibernate I could use.

Comment: I don't think there's a better way to do this because Hibernate querying basically consists of Criteria, HQL and of course the normal Session/Transaction thing. But good luck anyways.